# SQL query to select from one table based on a condition from a different table

Tags: mysql, sql

The first table have fields:

A_id, B_id, field1, field2

The second table have fields

C_id, A_id, B_id

I want to select all the rows in the first table that contain a B_id that is also present on the second table, moreover, I want only those rows with an specific A_id. I've tried to use JOIN statements, but I can't figure out the correct one. So far I have tried queries like this one, but they don't produce the desired result:

```
    SELECT post.* FROM post INNER JOIN subscription ON  subscription.iduser = 22 WHERE post.iduser = 22;
```

BTW, all of this is on MySQL.

Comment: Can you post the fields that these two tables have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write something like :

```
SELECT post.* 
FROM post 
LEFT JOIN subscription USING (iduser)
WHERE subscription.iduser = 22
```

If you have same field names in two tables you join , then `JOIN subscription ON  subscription.iduser = post.iduser` can be written as  `JOIN subscription USING( iduser )`.

Makes code a bit more readable.

---

update : fixed the typo

Comment: I made a small modification, but the basic idea works fine. SELECT post.* FROM post LEFT JOIN subscription USING (idpost) WHERE subscription.iduser = 22;